# Antlr - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Does anyone know anything about how Antlr works? I'm getting an error on a dev server:

**[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Antlr.StringTemplate.CommonGroupLoader.LocateFile(String filename) +19
   Antlr.StringTemplate.CommonGroupLoader.LoadGroup(String groupName, StringTemplateGroup superGroup, Type lexer) +67**

The same exact code works fine locally and I can see antlr.runtime.dll in the bin folder on the dev server.

Thanks for any guidance, I've never worked with Antlr before,
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being that Publish wasn't including the EmailTemplates folder...